# Drag/Drop - Identify and change which item is being dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want to drag three items to one drop point. Each item will be hidden on drop, and show/appends a different hidden div to the drop parent.

I can get the drag mechanics down but getting the drop to accept/fire different events based on whats being dropped into it is where I'm having an issue.

```
$(function(){
    $(".drag-item-1").draggable();
    $(".drag-item-2").draggable();
    $(".drag-item-3").draggable();
    $(".first-row").droppable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a drop function and implement that logic in there:

```
$( ".first-row" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass("drag-item-1")){
      $(this).css("background-color","red");
    } else if (ui.draggable.hasClass("drag-item-2")){
        $(this).css("background-color","blue");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
    }
  }
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: right. I understand that part. But how do i get it to fire a different event for each item dropped? In the above example, lets say the event is to change the background-color to red. But its going to do that with all 3 droppable items. How do i get it to do something different for each one?

Comment: Thank you. I understand that part. But your example is exactly where im stuck. I need to say, change the background to blue with item 2, and green with item 3. right now, all 3 change it red.

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear. Its not the Draggable items I want to change color, its the drop element itself. In this case the div with a class of ".first-row". So if i drag "drag-item-1" to the div "first-row", it should change red. Then repeat with "drag-item-2", which should change it blue, etc.

Comment: I think I got it. I just changed the ui.draggable.css to $(".first-row")

Comment: Using $(this) is a better option so you can use it on multiple droppables: http://jsfiddle.net/hcnhwvov/2/